# TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW in conjunction with @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS)

Tags: java, transactions, cdi, jta

I recently stumbled into the next piece of Java EE6 code:

```
   @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
        public void example(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) final ExampleEvent exampleEvent) {
```

Is `REQUIRES_NEW` really needed?
I mean example method will always be called **only** after any previous transaction  has ended successfully ( because of `TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS`).

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your are only observing `ExampleEvent`, so your `example()`-Method will not be called by itself (based on the `@TransactionAttribute`) unless your do something like this:

```
 @Inject
 private Event<ExampleEvent> exampleEvent;


 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public void example(@Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) final ExampleEvent exampleEvent) {
    ExampleEvent event = new ExampleEvent();
    exampleEvent.fire(event);
}
```

It makes sense to keep the `@TransactionAttribute` because the previous transaction just finished (`AFTER_SUCCESS`), so there is no current transaction therefore a new one is needed to be created. It can be possible that this would be done automatically (depending on the AS implementation) even without the annotation, but the result should be the same.

Comment: There is another bean with a method which fires an ExampleEvent. What i am asking is if  TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW is redundant because a new transaction will always be started anyway due to (during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_SUCCESS) .

Comment: Correct, thats what I mean, however there can be some requirements based on the implementation of your Application Server that you still have to declare it. If is working fine without the `@TransactionAttribute` you can stick to it.